# PHP Library: app_key error

Tags: php, oauth, eventbrite

I get this error when I try to login using the oAuth PHP example script (oauth2-login-example.php)

```
Please provide your Application Key in the URL as "?app_key=".
```

I have replaced the default `app_key` and `client_secret` with my codes.

You can test it here: http://www.daysofthedead.net/hub/examples/oauth2-login-example.php

Comment: After talking to ʀɣαɳĵ about this problem we thought it was because I was running PHP 5.2.17 (not 5.3). I've upgraded the server to run PHP 5.3.18 and I still get this error. Could it be because I am using cURLSSL and not cURL? (Documentation on cURLSSL says it has the same functions as cURL).

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply for an API key from Eventbrite for your account. 
Just head to https://www.eventbrite.com/api/key and create one. Then replace the "YOUR_APP_KEY" and "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET" with the values that Eventbrite provide.

```
$login_widget_html = Eventbrite::loginWidget(array( 'app_key' => 'YOUR_APP_KEY',
                                                    'client_secret' => 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I stated I replaced those in my original post.